# How can I re-configure Diff & Merge Tools to its default settings (clickable links) in Git Settings window in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to go back to the default settings regarding the Diff & Merge Tools in the Git Settings window ?

My Visual Studio Git Settings windows view is currently this:

[Team Explorer - Git Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKkF.png)

Answer (score 10):

These settings are controlled from your git configuration settings. There isn't a way to unset this in Visual Studio, but you can modify the git configurations.

You can modify these settings via the git commands on the command line. Open a command prompt and type one of the following commands (use the global switch, as it appears you have this set globally in the screen shot):

```
git config --edit --global
```

and remove the line for "tool" in the `diff` and `merge` sections.

Alternatively, you can remove the settings from the command line via the following git commands:

```
git config --global --unset diff.tool
git config --global --unset merge.tool
```

If you are on the Git Settings Team Explorer page when you unset the above values, you will need to manually refresh the page in order for it to pick up the changes (hit F5, or press the refresh button on the top of the Team Explorer page).

Comment: Thank you @jamill. But I have already 'global' settings as in the screenshot I attached above. I would like to go back to the original settings which enables clickable blue 'links' like diff or merge. Which command should I use ?!

Comment: @Sam490 The instructions above will "unset" the global configuration, and will go back to not having a specific diff / merge tool set (I thought this is what you meant by "default settings, but maybe I misunderstood). Which clickable blue links are you referring to? Do you mean the Diff / Merge Tool links on the Git Settings page?

Comment: Yes. I need to have Diff / Merge Tool links on Git Settings.

Comment: Did you unset the configured diff / merge tool as described above? That should reset the links to the original state. If not, what state is it in after setting the diff / merge tools?

Comment: Things are getting complicated now. I used the first command above (git config --edit --global) but can not get out of it anymore. Each time it saves .gitconfig.sw[different suffix] files and when I try recover one of them I can not quit the vim editor either with 'q' or 'quit'.

Comment: I found the way to quit, <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then `:wq`. But on Git Settings I have Diff Tool: None  | Use Visual Studio and Merge Tool: None | Use Visual Studio

Comment: Is that the default state you were looking for? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I need to have Diff Tool: Diff | Global and Merge Tool: Merge | Global (Diff, Merge and Global should be links).